# why is onclick event firing

Tags: reactjs, constants, bind

The following reactjs works fine.  I was wondering if it was possible to change the onDelete prop to just be the todo.id and then somehow invoke the removeTodo method, in other words is there a way to bind App.removeTodo to the const Todo?

So I played around  and made two changes:

```
const Todo = props =>(

<li>
 <input type='checkbox' checked={props.todo.checked} onChange={props.onToggle} />
 <button onClick={props.onDelete.removeTodo(props.todo.id)}>Delete</button>
 <span>{props.todo.text}</span>
</li>
```

and then:

```
<Todo
   key={todo.id}
   todo={todo}
   onToggle={()=>(this.checkBox(todo.id))}
   onDelete={this}
/>
```

The problem is the removeTodo is being fired whenever we addTodo

```js
import React from "react"
import "./App.css"

let id=0
const Todo = props =>(
  <li>
     <input type='checkbox' checked={props.todo.checked} onChange={props.onToggle} />
     <button onClick={props.onDelete}>Delete</button>
     <span>{props.todo.text}</span>
  </li>
)
class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(){
    super()
    this.state={
      todos:[]
    }
  }

  addTodo(e){
     this.setState({todos: [...this.state.todos,{
                               id:id++,
                               text:e.target.value,
                               checked:false}
                            ]
     })
     e.target.value=''
  }

  checkBox(id){
    this.setState({todos: this.state.todos.map(todo=>{
         if(todo.id !== id)return todo
         return{
           id:id,
           text:todo.text,
           checked: !todo.checked
         }
    })})
  }
  removeTodo(id){
    this.setState({todos: this.state.todos.filter(todo=>(todo.id !==id))})
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
         <span>Count of Todos: &nbsp; {this.state.todos.length}</span>
         <input type='text' placeholder='add Todos'
            onKeyPress={((e)=>(e.key==='Enter') ? this.addTodo(e):null)}/>
         <span>Checked Todos: &nbsp;
            {this.state.todos.filter(todo=>(todo.checked === true)).length}
         </span>

         <ul>
            {this.state.todos.map(todo=>(
             <Todo
                key={todo.id}
                todo={todo}
                onToggle={()=>(this.checkBox(todo.id))}
                onDelete={function(){this.removeTodo(todo.id)}.bind(this)}
             />
            ))}
         </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }

}


export default App
```

Comment: looks like you have already implemented what you want.

Comment: no, although the code works I'm trying to better understand how reactjs works.  Hence my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you call remove todo immediately as Todo render, see:

```
    <button onClick={props.onDelete.removeTodo(props.todo.id)}>Delete</button>
```

Try to pass function instead call it:

```
    <button onClick={() => props.onDelete.removeTodo(props.todo.id)}>Delete</button>
```